# How to enable remote desktop in Red Hat?

Tags: vnc, redhat-enterprise-linux

How to enable the remote desktop in a Red Hat system?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, every implementation is WM-dependent, but you may take a look at [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/)

Answer (score 1):

vncviewer is the solution.
you can see if it is installed by

```
$rpm -q vncviewer
```

if it is installed then you can share desktop by

```
$vncviewer <other computer ip>
```

it it is not installed then you need install it, this may help you-
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-tutorials-howtos-reference-material/971-installing-running-vnc-redhat-rpm-linux.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set up "remote desktop" feature on Linux using VNC. Part 2 and 3 in http://fclose.com/b/638/ introduce how to use VNC in a SSH tunnel. You can also use it directly.

You can install VNC server and viewer by

```
# yum install vnc vnc-server
```

or

```
# yum install tigervnc-server tigervnc
```